# get package name using PackageManager

Tags: android, listview

my listview displays installed apps having the internet permission, it works fine however, i am trying to enable clicking on list items and take the user to the screen where they can uninstall the app, my code works without any force closes but opens that uninstall screen only 0.25 second and goes back. this is because it is not getting the correct package name. How do i fix this?

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

         @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              getInstalledApps(this);
              ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, results);

              ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);

              listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                          long id) {
                      String packageName = results.get(position);
                      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                      intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
              });
         }

          private ArrayList<String> getInstalledApps(Context context) {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> applist = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
            Iterator<PackageInfo> it = applist.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                PackageInfo pk = (PackageInfo) it.next();
                if ((pk.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                    Log.v("system app using internet = ", ""+pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
                    continue;
                }

                if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, pk.packageName) ||
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, pk.packageName))
                    results.add("" + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
            }

            Log.v("app using internet = ", results.toString());

            return results;
        }
    }
```

also i would like to take it directly to the uninstall screen instead of taking it to the app info screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the **name of the app** in your results array instead of the **package name**, which is different.

Here's an example: the Facebook app has the name `Facebook` but its package name is `com.facebook.katana`

When querying the PackageManager, you should not only request `pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)` but also `pk.packageName` (in another array, for example).

So your code should be edited the following way:

1. Under `ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();` add `ArrayList<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<String>();`
2. Under `results.add("" + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));` add `packageNames.add(pk.packageName);`
   Use brackets with your `if (...)` here!
3. Replace `String packageName = results.get(position);` with `String packageName = packageNames.get(position);`

Comment: im not getting it :( can you post a snipped instead? thanks :D

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: i did everything like you said, it works with some apps, however, it also gives wrong positions for some apps, i click on gallery and it is opening kik.

Comment: Make sure this if has brackets: `if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED...)` and `result.add()` and `packageNames.add()` are both in the brackets

Comment: they all have some code next to them in brackets , just like " packageNames.add(pk.packageName);"

Comment: and it is still not working :C

Comment: It should look like this: 
`if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET, pk.packageName) || PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == packageManager .checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, pk.packageName)) {
                    results.add("" + pk.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
                    packageNames.add(pk.packageName);
    }
            }`

Comment: awesome. im accepting this answer, ill upvote if you tell me how to set a similar image on the left of every list item (like ic_launcher) :D

Comment: Put an ImageView in your list item and then use `Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pk.packageName);` to set it on the list item. If you are stuck again, create a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: Sorry but this is out of scope of the question, and I also got other work to do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this
    ArrayList<AppInfodata> appsDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void getAllApps() {

            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            List apps = packageManager
                    .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH);
            if (apps != null && !apps.isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++) {
                    PackageInfo p = (PackageInfo) apps.get(i);
                    ApplicationInfo appInfo = null;
                    try {
                        appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(p.packageName,
                                0);

                        AppInfodata app = new AppInfodata();
                        app.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
                                .toString();
                        app.packagename = p.packageName;

                      app.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);


                            appsDataList.add(app);
                        }

                    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // sort the list of applications alphabetically

            }
            public class AppInfodata {
        String appname;
        String packagename;

        Drawable icon;


    }

class AppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppInfoData>
{
AppListAdapter(Context context,int resource,ArrayList<AppInfoData> datalist)
{
super(context,resource,datalist);
}
getView(.....)
{
AppInfoData data =getItem(position);
}
```

}

Comment: how do i show it in listview?

Comment: also i want my custom image next to all apps, not their own icon, how do i do that?

Comment: you can add your own image in this field app.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);

Comment: Its depend on you if you have resource than change the datatype in int in AppInfoClass otherwise as per your requirement

Comment: but how do i add the listview? this doesnt fit in my code. can you give me the full implementation?

Comment: you can Create a arrayList like ArrayList<AppInfodata> appsDataList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: ok I can Update the Code

Comment: i can update the code plz check